Scheduler Service Timeout
I'm seeing the below error and it is crashing the Scheduler Services.
Can anyone check this and let me know how to investigate this issue and fix it?
[Error] - An error occurred whilst trying to load Scheduler. Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. CdcSoftware.Respond.DataAccess    at CdcSoftware.Respond.DataAccess.SqlServer.SqlSchedulesDA.LoadAll()
   at CdcSoftware.Respond.DataRepository.EditableRepositoryBase`1.LoadData()
   at CdcSoftware.Respond.DataRepository.EditableRepositoryBase`1.LoadDataIntoCache()
   at CdcSoftware.Respond.DataRepository.SchedulesRepository.GetAll()
   at CdcSoftware.Respond.BusinessLayer.SchedulesManager.GetForScheduler()

I don't have any clue where to check and hence seeking help.

CdcSoftware.Respond.BusinessLayer.SchedulesManager.GetForScheduler() - would be a start. Is that your code or 3rd Party?

Its coming from the Scheduler Services. Its the code coming from the Product I guess.

Is the SQL Database and the Server it is running on up and healthy? And reachable from where the scheduling service is running? Looks like a connectivity problem to me. Maybe also check all of the configurations. Is it trying to access the correct database?

The scheduler service checks the package scheduled for running in the database and executes as per scheduled time. I've found that the issue not with the application, it is from the emails that is triggered by the Scheduler Service. The sending of email is crashing the scheduler service. This was found after disabling the email sending functionality in the product. Thank you for your inputs.
